# git push --tags failing due to a submodule, which tag?

Tags: git, tags, git-submodules

When I do `git push --tags` I get

```
The following submodule paths contain changes that can
not be found on any remote:
  packages/jpl
```

This apparently due to one of the tags as normal pushing works and so does pushing a specific tag using `git push origin <tag>`.   Unfortunately git gives me no clue which of the 699 tags (old project) is causing this.   I'm now running

```
for t in $(git tag) do;
  echo $t
  git push origin $t
done
```

Its already running for a long time.   I'd assume there is a quicker way to find the culprits, no?